# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget, error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opengl

I am working in a task in Visual Studio with QT and OpenGL.

I am really having problems with configuring QT and to run it. I fixed many errors and now it isn't showing me any errors, but when I compile it it goes almost until the end, and then it stops. Here are the logs that VS is showing:

```
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Cored.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Widgetsd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Guid.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5OpenGL.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Widgets.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Gui.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Core.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'testClasa2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
The program '[5200] testClasa2.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

In the end of the log as you can see it says: **QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget**  I really don't know what it means :(

Here are the classes:

main.cpp:

```
#include "testclasa2.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    testClasa2 w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

testClass2.cpp:

```
#include "testclasa2.h"

testClasa2::testClasa2(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

testClasa2::~testClasa2()
{

}
```

testClass2.h:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASA2_H
#define TESTCLASA2_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include "ui_testclasa2.h"

class testClasa2 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testClasa2(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~testClasa2();

private:
    Ui::testClasa2Class ui;
};

#endif // TESTCLASA2_H
```

taliWidget.cpp:

```
#include "taliWidget.h"

//#include "taliWidget.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>
taliWidget::taliWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

//taliWidget::~taliWidget()
//{
//}
void initiliazeGL(){

}
//void paintGL(){
//
//}
//void resizeGL(int w, int h){
//
//}
```

taliWidget.h:

```
#ifndef TALIWIDGET_H
#define TALIWIDGET_H

#include <QtOpenGL\qglwidget>
class taliWidget :
    public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit taliWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    //~taliWidget();

    void initiliazeGL();
    /*void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);*/
};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136649/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qwidget)

Comment: I checked that post, but I couldn't find the solution based on the answer the guy have given there. And the code is totally different from his post. If I would now how to solve it I wouldn't post here... the problem is that I can't find any solution to my problem and I am searching the whole day.

Comment: At which point did your program work and what have you changed since? Try to backtrace. You should not wait too long before trying to re-run your programs, so you should have an idea of what you did that ended up breaking it.

Comment: the problem is that it never worked :( I tried it in QT Creator and there it works the same stuff. But here in Visual Studio, it doesn't work. Even though now i don't have errors, I am not able to execute it :(

Comment: I think you might be running into IDE configuration issues. Are you using their Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: I installed the QT add-on so I can work with QT in Visual Studio. I really don't have any idea how the hell to solve this!! :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have VS or Windows. I'd probably suggest using Qt Creator while you manage to figure it out. You may need to check their support forums instead.