# "Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" error, but only on Windows builds?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, vtk

I am working on a CMAKE C++ project which uses the QT Libraries. (For me, 5.15.3, for others 5.12.x)

In this project, there is a `class Vtk3DViewer : public QWidget`. In its constructor, it tries to create one of its member variables, which is of type `QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget`. This is from the VTK libraries. (Located in include\vtk-9.2\QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget.h)

For me, this `new QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget()` call within the constructor of my QWidget fails with the following error:

> "Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget"

But that's just it, we *do* create a QApplication in `main()` well before this point. And this **only happens on Windows**. Linux builds appear to not have any issue.

Switching from Debug to RelWithDebugInfo moves the error - making it happen much earlier and on creating a `QToolBarExt` instead.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Here is an example of `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Set info for settings & registry
    QApplication::setOrganizationName(COMPANY_NAME);
    QApplication::setOrganizationDomain(COMPANY_DOMAIN);
    QApplication::setApplicationName(APP_NAME);

    // Set up for software-based backend for VTK
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/main-window/favicon.ico"));

    // Instantiate singletons
    TaskExecutionManager::getInstance(); // Instantiate the task manager
    DataDispatcher::getInstance();

    // Create main window with default size
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    // Start application event loop
    return a.exec();
}
```

Then the main window's constructor calls:

```
void MainWindow::initializeMainWindow(Ui::MainWindow* ui)
{

    this->setDockOptions(AnimatedDocks | AllowNestedDocks | AllowTabbedDocks | GroupedDragging);
    // Main toolbar
    m_topToolBar = new QToolBarExt(this); // This causes a "Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" error
}
```

Comment: *Why is this happening* This is happening because the program does not construct QApplication. *how do I fix it* Construct a QApplication before a QWidget.

Comment: That's just it however, we *do* create a QApplication well before this constructor is called.

Comment: Maybe the file that creates QApplication is not included to cmake builds on Windows.

Comment: The file that creates the Qapplication is within our main() function. It's definitely built, as otherwise we would not be able to run the application at all. I've now clarified that in the original question.

Comment: Then the widget is likely a global object. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I removed my comment about the message handler because I think @273K is correct and in that case it won't work because that happens before main()

Comment: So, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136649/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qwidget. Please someone close the question as a duplicate, I spent my vote for need debug details.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, these widgets are not global, but member variables. In the second case, it is a member variable of the QMainWindow being created in main(). I'll try to add some code clarifying this.

Comment: @273K I have added some code that should help, even if it is not a perfect minimal exmaple.

Comment: You seemed to post a fixed code, MainWindow is created there after QApplication, that is correct.

Comment: @273 So if it is correct, why do I get the error?

Comment: It's not a mystery. You have a global QWidget object, that is not shown.

Comment: @273K The error occurs on a QWidget that *is* a member, not a global. Are you saying the error occurred elsewhere, but I'm getting the error delayed until the creation of the following QWidget after the erroneous one? I cannot post the entire source, but I will look over it again in case.

Comment: Yes, it can be delayed till a main window creation. It may be seen earlier in a console if the app runs from a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that VTK was built in RELEASE, while our project was built in DEBUG.

(I did not see this as an issue, since we would never need to step into/debug VTK's code)

It appears this cryptic/incorrect error message will appear under these circumstances. Ensuring VTK and the project it includes are compiled the same way fixes it.